# Sale Order Line And Manufacturing Order BOM Creation Process

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I need to know that , after the confirmation of sale order how to generate and also process and the function in bill of materials field  in manufacturing order?

Thank You!

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow, please se this: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Sale and MRP modules.
2. Create few products for example: product and product_component
3. Create a BoM for product, where material is a product_component
4. Set Make to Order in product, and set it as manufacture
5. create sale order, sell one product and go to your MO.

Comment: Thank You, and i just need to know this process from backend side.can you explain?

Comment: I dont know exactly what do you want to know. 
When sale order is confirmed, then Procurement is being created. Procurement is ran by scheduler. So you should search there.